# Swap number test case in spock

Tags: java, spock

I am just trying to go through with Spock test framework and as per the documentation it looks better than JUnit and tried to write the simple test case but somehow it's not working.

Class:

```
public class SwapTwoNumber {
    public void swapNumber(int a,int b){
        a =a+b;
        b=a-b;
        a=a-b;

    }
}
```

Spock Test Groovy:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class SwapTwoNumberTest extends Specification{
    def "swap to number as given. #a and #b"() {
     given:
      int a = 5
      int b = 6
     when:
      SwapTwoNumber sw =Mock()
      sw.swapNumber(a,b)
      then:
      a==6
      b==5

    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it's not working" look like?

Comment: Note that Java is call-by-value so passing `a` and `b` to `swapNumber` won't actually do anything visible to the caller. `a` will still be 5 and `b` will still be 6. You'd need to pass a reference (also a kind of value) to a mutable container, e.g. `AtomicInteger` (as a simple example, it's not the actual use-case that class exists for) and then call `set(...)` on those.

Comment: Is your call to `Mock()` correct?  You shouldn't be mocking the thing you are testing (not to mention your code is simple, there is no need to mock anything)

Comment: Agree @mattfreake but Thomas pointed out correctly wrt to implementation.

Comment: This code is wrong on so many levels, I hardly know where to begin: The swap action is cryptic, just in order to save a temporary variable. What do you think you are going to optimise here? Then you mock the class under test, making `swapNumber` do nothing at all! You don't understand primitive or immutable types like `int` and `Integer`. You use a `void` method, the only side effect of which is modification of internal state (which would work for object types, not for primitives or their immutable wrapper classes). Just learn programming basics first, then focus on testing next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the testing framework you mentioned but this is most likely not a framework problem. You are passing primitives arguments.

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

> Primitive arguments, such as an int or a double, are passed into methods by value. This means that any changes to the values of the parameters exist only within the scope of the method. When the method returns, the parameters are gone and any changes to them are lost.